# Lock de registro

Tags: mysql

Como eu poderia lockar um registro no MySQL?

Por exemplo, tenho um registro que está sendo acessado pelo usuário 000, e quero lockar esse registro para que usuarios diferentes de 000 não consiga acessa-lo. Isso é possivel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente você precisa se assegurar dos seguintes dois pré requisitos para que o lock de registro funcione:

1. A engine de armazenamento de sua tabela deve ser configurada para
   InnoDB.
2. Sua consulta de lock do registro deve ser executada após iniciar uma
   transação.

Você pode executar lock de registro no MySQL de duas formas:

**1) SELECT … FOR UPDATE**

Qualquer lock concluindo com o comando `FOR UPDATE` não irá permitir que outras transações leiam, atualizem ou excluam o registro. Outras transações poderão ler esses registros somente após a primeira transação ser concluída (commited) ou cancelada (roll back).

Exemplo:

```
; Esta consulta não irá permitir que outras transações leiam o registro com id=10;
; Ela também não irá permitir atualizações ou exclusões di registro.
SELECT * FROM NomeDaTabela WHERE id=10 FOR UPDATE
```

**2) LOCK IN SHARED MODE**

Qualquer lock com o comando `LOCK IN SHARED MODE` irá permitir outras transações lerem o registro bloqueado porém não irão permitir que outras transações atualizem ou excluam o registro. Outras transações poderão atualizar ou excluir o registro quando a primeira transação for concluída ou cancelada.

Exemplo:

```
; Esta consulta não irá permitir que outras transações atualizem ou excluam o registro de id=10.
; Ela permite que outras transações leiam o registro de id=10.
SELECT * FROM NomeDaTabela WHERE id=10 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

*Essa resposta foi adaptada do artigo em inglês **"Row Locking With MySQL"**, disponível em http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/11/row-locking-with-mysql/*

Comment: Legal, o que eu preciso saber agora, é como dar unlock no registro, pois preciso que quando um registro for aberto, ele fique lockado por 5 min.

Comment: +Rafael, esses 5 minutos que você fala é o tempo máximo que o registro deverá ficar lockado, ou toda vez que você fizer um lock você deseja que ele dure exatamente 5 minutos?

Comment: Quando eu fazer o lock, ele deve durar exatamente 5 minutos

Comment: Creio que o lock apenas permite definir o timeout máximo, mas não mínimo. A solução então teria que ser a nível de aplicação, e não a nível de banco de dados. Por exemplo, para cada acesso à tabela, sua aplicação armazena o usuário que está acessando e a hora do acesso, e para cada novo acesso a essa tabela o sistema então valida se é outro usuário. Se for outro usuário, ele verifica se já passou os cinco minutos desde quando o primeiro usuário acessou. Caso outro usuário acesse e já tenham passado os cinco minutos, o sistema então grava esse novo usuário e o novo horário de bloqueio.

Comment: Tabela? ou registro da tabela?

Comment: Aos registros da tabela, para cada um deles.

Comment: Nesse link, parece que é possivel fazer a nivel de banco de dados, alterando o timeout, dê uma olhada: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-other-changes-innodb_lock_wait_timeout.html

Comment: @Vynstus Dei uma olhada, e diz que "The length of time a transaction waits for a resource, **before giving up and rolling back the statement**, is determined by the value of the configuration parameter innodb_lock_wait_timeout". Esse tempo é o que a transação vai esperar até que seja concluída ou que dê timeout por não ter conseguido ser concluída dentro do tempo esperado. Porém não mantém aberta a transação por N minutos. Outra coisa: manter a transação aberta por N minutos **bloquearia todas as tabelas**, tornando o sistema ficaria indisponível, o que é inviável para qualquer aplicação.

Comment: @Vynstus a documentação em português está disponível no link http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-4.1-pt.a4.pdf, e essa variável **innodb_lock_wait_timeout** está descrita na **página 474**, seção *7.5.3. Opções de Inicialização do InnoDB*, caso possa lhe interessar.

Comment: Entendi. Uma duvida, o lock da engine Innodb é a nivel de linha, nesse caso não é possivel lockar um tabela innodb inteira? usando LOCK TABLE?

Answer (score 1):

Este processo é conhecido como **Deadlock**.

Confira a documentação do MySQL, espero que este link ajude você assim como outras pessoas:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-lock-modes.html

Um bloqueio compartilhado (S) permite a transação que mantém o bloqueio para ler um registro.

Um bloqueio exclusivo (X) permite a transação que mantém o bloqueio de atualizar ou excluir uma linha.

Exemplo:

Este exemplo envolve dois clientes, cliente A e cliente B.

O cliente A cria a tabela contendo um registro e inicia a transação selecionando está linha, segue:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.07 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t (i) VALUES(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM t WHERE i = 1 LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
+------+
| i    |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)
```

Em seguida, o cliente B inicia a transação e executa um delete nesta linha:

```
mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELETE FROM t WHERE i = 1;
```

Resultado:

```
mysql> DELETE FROM t WHERE i = 1;
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock;
try restarting transaction
```

Este exemplo foi tirado do site do MySQL, não detalhei todo o processo, mas você pode consultar no link que lhe forneci.

Espero que lhe ajude assim como me ajudou a aprender algo novo.

Comment: Legal!! E para eu finalizar a transação é só eu dar um COMMIT? ou seja, para dar unlock no registro.

Comment: Como está no exemplo acredito que não precisa dar COMMIT, o MySQL vai executar o COMMIT quando chegar ao último comando SQL em uma instrução. E assim que o cliente A finalizar com um COMMIT o registro será desbloqueado para o cliente B por exemplo.

Comment: Ultimo comando SQL? Não entendi...

Comment: Por exemplo, você insere uma linha e NÃO da COMMIT, e logo em seguida você da um SELECT, estes dois comandos apenas, o último comando será o SELECT e logo em baixo o próprio MySQL se encarrega de dar o COMMIT;

Comment: Como ele vai saber que o select é minha ultima instrução SQL? eu poderia inserir mais instruções, como count max etc