# Travar registro (lock) no SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi

Utilizando SQL Server e Delphi, preciso controlar para que em uma certa tabela do banco de dados duas alterações não possam ser feitas ao mesmo tempo no mesmo registro, não posso iniciar o update se já houver outra alteração em andamento. Preciso saber se isso é possível. O cenário é o seguinte: tem-se a tabela TabelaTeste com n registros, e dois terminais de acesso, A e B. Se o terminal A deseja alterar algum dado do registro 1, ele deve adquirir um lock nessa linha, de forma que se o terminal B tentar alterar essa mesma linha ele recebe uma memsagem de erro. Mas alteração de linhas diferentes é permitida.
Para isso consegui obter um certo sucesso. O fluxo é o seguinte atualmente:

1 - Transação iniciada;

2 - Execução de uma query para travar o registro solicitado:
-> 'select * from TabelaTeste with (updlock, nowait) where codigo = :codigo';

3 - Se não der erro ao executar a query acima, o registro está livre e o fluxo continua, senão é gerado um erro e a operação é abortada;

4 - Realizada a operação de update necessária;

5 - Transação é comitada;

Estou tendo problema com a seguinte situação:

1 - Terminal A inicia a alteração da linha 1 dessa tabela;

2 - Terminal B inicia a alteração da linha 2 dessa tabela. Aqui aqui tudo bem, são linhas diferentes;

3 - Terminal A tenta executar seu update (passo nº 4 do esquema acima). Aqui está o problema, enquanto o Terminal B não concluir ou cancelar seu processamento, esse update aqui não será realizado, deixando o usuário esperando;

Se alguém possui algum conhecimento para auxiliar, dizer se é a combinação dos hints que estão sendo utilizados no select, ou se realmente essa situação não é possível.

Comment: Boa tarde @Túlio.  Por acaso eu hoje passei por uma pergunta bem parecida.  De uma olhada para ver se é esse o seu caso..: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73667/lock-de-registro.  Neste link aponta para um outro link que achei que se encaixa no seu problema..:  https://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/11/row-locking-with-mysql/  . Se esses links forem úteis de uma resposta informando isso :) Abraços.

Comment: Bom dia Ricardo, mas não é o mesmo caso, embora semelhantes. A sintaxe entre o Mysql e o SQL Server são diferentes inclusive. Meu caso está mais diretamente ligado ao fato de necessitar que o update dê um lock na tabela em nível de linha, e não em nível de página ou tabela, como parece estar ocorrendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido, além de alterar o índice da tabela para não permitir lock por página (alter index MyIndex on MyTable set (allow_page_locks = off)), removi um campo que era preenchido por uma trigger e funcionou.